# Extract by value and put it in the beginning of the list using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list like this:

```
l=[1,2,3,4,5]
```

I want to keep 2 and 4 in the beginning of the list, the result should look like:

```
 l=[2,4,1,3,5]
```

basically I want to extract the elements from the list by value and put those in front of the list.

What I could do,

```
for i in [2,4]:
    l.remove(l)
```

and after that I could push it into the list again using another loop,

But I am looking for a better method, an one-liner may be.

I am using python to solve it.

Comment: you mean `l.remove(i)` (not `l.remove(l)`). then it's just a case of `[2,4] + l` (sorting is overkill and less readable too IMO)

Comment: @bharatk it's not a question about odd or even, it could be string or anything. So please remove duplicate option.

Comment: @KallolSamanta You should update your question, add context list may be contained a string or anything,  better understand for future prospect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sorted()` with custom `key=`:

```
l=[1,2,3,4,5]

print(sorted(l, key=lambda k: k not in (2, 4)))
```

Prints:

```
[2, 4, 1, 3, 5]
```

OR:

```
print(sorted(l, key=lambda k, s={2, 4}: k not in s))
```

Answer (score 3):

Just sort the list, with key as a function that would check if the element is present or not in the set of elements to be moved

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> moved = {2,4}
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda e: -(e in moved))
[2, 4, 1, 3, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple way of doing it:

```py
l=[1,2,3,4,5]

final_list = [i for i in l if i in [2,4]] # add the numbers that are 2 or 4
final_list += [i for i in l if i not in [2,4]] # add the other numbers

print(final_list)
```

Output:

```py
[2, 4, 1, 3, 5]
```

First we had the numbers of the list `l` than are `2` or `4` to the `final_list` and then we had the numbers of the list `l` than are not `2` or `4`.

Answer (score 0):

If the logic is to create a sorted list with even numbers at the beginning, you can use this:

```
new_list = sorted(my_list, key= lambda x: (x%2 !=0))
```

It can be used for any list of integers:

```
my_list = range(1, 10)
new_list = sorted(my_list, key= lambda x: (x%2 !=0))
#  [2, 4, 6, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```